# Argument of \begin has an extra }. \par

Tags: lists, moderncv

I keep getting this up and I don't see the issue

> ```
> Argument of \begin has an extra }.
> <inserted text> 
>                 \par 
> l.78 \item
>            <Item 1>
> ```

This is the doc

```
\section{Previous Jobs}
\cventry{2011 --}{Teacher}{\textsc{Text}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\item Item 5
\item Item 6
\item Item 7
\item Item 8
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please give a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/120578) that we can test and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried it with `\cventry{2011 --}{Teacher}{\textsc{Text}}{}{}{}`?

Comment: `\cventry` takes 6 arguments, not 3 as you've indicated.

Answer (score 2):

Command `\cventry` is defined to have 6 arguments, and arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty (but you have to write `{}`):

```
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
```

With the following MWE (I added the missing `{}`, see marked code with `<======`)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Previous Jobs}
\cventry{2011 --}{Teacher}{\textsc{Text}}{}{}{} % <=====================
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\item Item 5
\item Item 6
\item Item 7
\item Item 8
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

you can compile without any error! The result is:

[image: resulting pdf]